Route on Nuxt 2 fires 2 page views for every visit on nested route when using vue-gtag with Google Analytics 4

I am using Nuxt 2 with a custom router with the nuxtjs/router module

I am using vue-gtag library to get Google Analytics 4 running as per the issue mentioned here

This custom route fires 2 page views for every visit on NewsDetail and 1 page view otherwise


router/routes.js
...
  {
    path: '/news/:tag?',
    alias: '/',
    component: Index,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'NewsList',
        component: NewsListWrapper,
        props: true,
      },
      {
        path: '/news/:tag?/:id([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})/:title',
        name: 'NewsDetail',
        component: NewsDetailWrapper,
        props: true,
      },
    ],
  },
...

When visiting NewsDetail it fires 2 events but fires only 1 event for NewsList above
Here's a part of my nuxt.config.js
...
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/axios.js',
    '~/plugins/buefy.js',
    '~/plugins/fontawesome.js',
    '~/plugins/utils.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-gtag.client.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-gtag.server.js',
    '~/plugins/vanilla-cookieconsent.client.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-native-websocket.client.js',
  ],
...

plugins/vue-gtag-client.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'

const vueGtag = ({ app, $config: { GTAG_MEASUREMENT_ID } }, inject) => {
  Vue.use(
    VueGtag,
    {
      appName: 'ch_ui',
      bootstrap: false,
      config: { id: GTAG_MEASUREMENT_ID },
      deferScriptLoad: true,
      enabled: false,
      onError(error) {
        console.error('script failed to load', error)
      },
      pageTrackerTemplate(to) {
        return {
          page_title: to.name,
          page_path: to.fullPath,
        }
      },
      params: {
        anonymize_ip: true,
      },
    },

    app.router,
  )
  inject('gtag', Vue.$gtag)
}

export default vueGtag

plugins/vue-gtag-server.js
const vueGtag = ({ app, $config: { GTAG_MEASUREMENT_ID } }) => {
  const preloadLinks = [
    {
      rel: 'preload',
      as: 'script',
      href: `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-${GTAG_MEASUREMENT_ID}`,
    },
    {
      rel: 'preconnect',
      href: 'https://www.google-analytics.com/',
    },
  ]
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    if (typeof app.head === 'function') {
      console.error("We can't add the preload links if head is a function")
    } else if (app.head) {
      app.head.link = [...(app.head.link || []), ...preloadLinks]
    } else {
      app.head = {
        link: preloadLinks,
      }
    }
  }
}

export default vueGtag


Anyone has any ideas how to make NewsDetail NOT FIRE 2 page views for each visit?
